# How to get all combinations from multiple arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, matrix, combinations

Supposing I have these 3 arrays

```
$array1 = array(1,2);
$array2 = array(4,5);
$array3 = array(7,8);
```

I need this output

```
1 4 7
1 4 8
1 5 7
1 5 8
2 4 7
2 4 8
2 5 7
2 5 8
```

One of my problems is that my array myght vary from 3 to 15 different arrays and each myght be empty (I might add a 0 just not to be empty) or have many values.
If I have an empty array I also need to count that as a valid column. These values will be used to fill up a database in a specific order.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: I tried a foreach() cascate for each array but that didn't work

Comment: Let's see. Post it here.

Comment: The best I could do was start with something like this 

foreach ($array1 as $a1) {
    $var .= $a1;
    foreach ($array2 as $a2) {
        $var .= $a2;
        foreach ($array3 as $a3) {
            $var .= $a3;
        }
    }
    $var .= '<br />';
}

But I can't figure out how to fill the first columns with the values I need

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Comment: @Caio Favero So your attempt was almost correct. Just move your $var lines inside the last nested loop.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ But his code still wouldn't be very flexible..

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out about that pushing my $var to the last foreach. But as @Rizier123 said, it's not flexible, but I can make it work

Comment: @CaioFavero Did you take a look at the answers down below?

Comment: Yeah, I did. Quite elegant. I'll try and use it and see if it works the way I need. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### How many combinations are there?

So first the question how many combinations are there? And the answer is you have to multiply the amount of every array with each other.

So (c = amount<sup>1</sup>):

> c<sub>array 1</sub> * c<sub>array 2</sub> * ... * c<sub>array n</sub>

And specific for your example:

> c<sub>array 1</sub> * c<sub>array 2</sub> * c<sub>array 3</sub> = 2 * 2 * 2 = 8

<sub>*1 And if you wonder why I chose c for amount, because of the function count() in php</sub>

#### Getting all combinations together

How do we get now all combinations with the amount of arrays, which we have?

We loop through all our combinations, which we already have(Starting off with one combination, an "empty combination" (`$combinations = [[]];`)), and for each combination we go through our next data array and combine each combination with each input data to a new combination.

Now we do this until we get the desired length for each combination.

So as an example:

```
Array with the elements (Empty array is '[]'):

[
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
]
```

```
                               //↓ new combinations for the next iteration
                               │
array NAN*:

    Combinations:
                  - []         │  -> []
                                  │
array 1 [1,2]:      ┌─────────────┤
                    │             │
    Combinations:   v             v
                  - []    + 1  │  -> [1]  
                  - []    + 2  │  -> [2]   
                                  │
array 2 [3,4]:      ┌─────────────┤
                    │             │
    Combinations:   v             v
                  - []    + 3  │  -> [3]
                  - []    + 4  │  -> [4]
                  - [1]   + 3  │  -> [1,3]  //desired length 2 as we have 2 arrays 
                  - [1]   + 4  │  -> [1,4]  //desired length 2 as we have 2 arrays 
                  - [2]   + 3  │  -> [2,3]  //desired length 2 as we have 2 arrays 
                  - [2]   + 4  │  -> [2,4]  //desired length 2 as we have 2 arrays    
                               //↑ All combinations here
```

<sub>* NAN: not a number</sub>

So as you can see in the above example we now have all combinations with the length of the amount of all arrays which we have.

But to get only the combinations with the desired length we are overwriting the result array each iteration, so that at the end only the combinations with the expected length are in the results array.

#### Code:

```
<?php

    $array1 = array(1,2);
    $array2 = array(4,5);
    $array3 = array(7,8);


    $combinations = [[]];
    $data = [
        $array1,
        $array2,
        $array3,
    ];
    $length = count($data);

    for ($count = 0; $count < $length; $count++) {
        $tmp = [];
        foreach ($combinations as $v1) {
            foreach ($data[$count] as $v2)
                $tmp[] = array_merge($v1, [$v2]);

        }
        $combinations = $tmp;
    }

    print_r($combinations);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 7
        )
    //...
    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 8
        )

)
```

---

For associative arrays you only have to do a slight modification, which is:

1. First assign the arrays keys to a variable with `array_keys()`, e.g.

   ```
   $keys = array_keys($data);
   ```
2. Use the keys in the second foreach loop to access the data array, means from:

   ```
   foreach ($data[$count] as $v2)
   ```

   to:

   ```
   foreach ($data[$keys[$count]] as $v2)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$color = array('Blue','Red','Black','Green');
$size = array('L','M','S','XL','XXL');
$type  = array('Half selevs','full seleves');
$options = [
            $color,
            $size,
            $type,
        ];
$combinations = getCombinations($options);

print_r($combinations);

function getCombinations($options){ 

            $combinations = [[]];

            for ($count = 0; $count < count($options); $count++) {
                $tmp = [];
                foreach ($combinations as $v1) {
                    foreach ($options[$count] as $v2)
                        $tmp[] = array_merge($v1, [$v2]);

                }
                $combinations = $tmp;
            }

            return $combinations;
        }
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Blue
            [1] => L
            [2] => Half selevs
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Blue
            [1] => L
            [2] => full seleves
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Blue
            [1] => M
            [2] => Half selevs
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Blue
            [1] => M
            [2] => full seleves
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Blue
            [1] => S
            [2] => Half selevs
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Blue
            [1] => S
            [2] => full seleves
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Blue
            [1] => XL
            [2] => Half selevs
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Blue
            [1] => XL
            [2] => full seleves
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => Blue
            [1] => XXL
            [2] => Half selevs
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => Blue
            [1] => XXL
            [2] => full seleves
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => Red
            [1] => L
            [2] => Half selevs
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => Red
            [1] => L
            [2] => full seleves
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => Red
            [1] => M
            [2] => Half selevs
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => Red
            [1] => M
            [2] => full seleves
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => Red
            [1] => S
            [2] => Half selevs
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => Red
            [1] => S
            [2] => full seleves
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => Red
            [1] => XL
            [2] => Half selevs
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => Red
            [1] => XL
            [2] => full seleves
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => Red
            [1] => XXL
            [2] => Half selevs
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [0] => Red
            [1] => XXL
            [2] => full seleves
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [0] => Black
            [1] => L
            [2] => Half selevs
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [0] => Black
            [1] => L
            [2] => full seleves
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [0] => Black
            [1] => M
            [2] => Half selevs
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [0] => Black
            [1] => M
            [2] => full seleves
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [0] => Black
            [1] => S
            [2] => Half selevs
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [0] => Black
            [1] => S
            [2] => full seleves
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [0] => Black
            [1] => XL
            [2] => Half selevs
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [0] => Black
            [1] => XL
            [2] => full seleves
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [0] => Black
            [1] => XXL
            [2] => Half selevs
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [0] => Black
            [1] => XXL
            [2] => full seleves
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [0] => Green
            [1] => L
            [2] => Half selevs
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [0] => Green
            [1] => L
            [2] => full seleves
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [0] => Green
            [1] => M
            [2] => Half selevs
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [0] => Green
            [1] => M
            [2] => full seleves
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [0] => Green
            [1] => S
            [2] => Half selevs
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [0] => Green
            [1] => S
            [2] => full seleves
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [0] => Green
            [1] => XL
            [2] => Half selevs
        )

    [37] => Array
        (
            [0] => Green
            [1] => XL
            [2] => full seleves
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [0] => Green
            [1] => XXL
            [2] => Half selevs
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [0] => Green
            [1] => XXL
            [2] => full seleves
        )

)
```