# Creating string combination from dynamic array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, combinations

Here is my problem:

I have a dynamic array:

```
$variants = array (
  array ('red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'),
  array ('S', 'M', 'L'),
  array ('plastic', 'cotton', 'paper', 'glass'),
  ...
  ... other dynamic arrays
  ... 
  array ('X', 'Y', 'Z'),
);
```

and i need all the combinations as the result, like this:

```
$combinations = array(
  'red-S-plastic-...-X', (start of combination)
  'red-S-plastic-...-Y',
  'red-S-plastic-...-Z',
  ...
  ...
  ...
  'blue-L-cotton-...-X',
  'blue-L-cotton-...-Y',
  'blue-L-cotton-...-Z',
  ...
  ...
  ...
  'yellow-L-glass-...-Z'(end of combination)
);
```

any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512570/how-to-get-all-combinations-from-multiple-arrays

Comment: That's the task at hand, what have you tried to solve it and what does not work?