# Best way to find all the combination (72^5) and insert into Mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I'm having a hard time finding a solution for this and I don't even know if it's possible...

I'm developing a small app where I have 5 types of items with different stats, 7 levels (some have only 3 levels), and I would like to find all the items stats combinaisons.

Ex:

- Item 1 lvl 1, Item 1 lvl 1 + Item 1 lvl 1 + Item 1 lvl 1 + Item 1 lvl 1
- Item 1 lvl 2, Item 1 lvl 1 + Item 1 lvl 1 + Item 1 lvl 1 + Item 1 lvl 1
- Item 1 lvl 3, Item 1 lvl 1 + Item 1 lvl 1 + Item 1 lvl 1 + Item 1 lvl 1
- Item 1 lvl 4, Item 1 lvl 1 + Item 1 lvl 1 + Item 1 lvl 1 + Item 1 lvl 1
- ....
- Item 7 lvl 7, Item 1 lvl 1 + Item 1 lvl 1 + Item 1 lvl 1 + Item 1 lvl 1
- Item 7 lvl 7, Item 1 lvl 2 + Item 1 lvl 1 + Item 1 lvl 1 + Item 1 lvl 1
- Item 7 lvl 7, Item 1 lvl 3 + Item 1 lvl 1 + Item 1 lvl 1 + Item 1 lvl 1
- ...

So it will generate around 1 934 917 632 possibilities.

What should be the best approach to do this?

Is it ok to store those values into a Mysql Database?

Is there any way to optimize this? Do the calculation live with a lot of filters to reduce the possible combinaisons?

I already try [How to get all combinations from multiple arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512570/how-to-get-all-combinations-from-multiple-arrays) it works fine, but I only test with 40 possibilities, I'am more concerned about the Database part...

**EDIT:**
Each combinaison will give an amount of token, the tool would be used to find the combinaison that give more token than a previous combinaison. –

Thank you guys!

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to understand the question. Or better what is behind this question. Obviously it _is_ possible to compute a huge number of combinations of whatever. And it certainly also obviously _is_ possible to store such data in a database. Whether that makes sense is a completely different question.

Comment: Hi @arkascha! Sorry english is not my main language, I didn't realize that the main point of my question wasn't very clear.

It's the first time I face that amount of data and I wanted to know if it was possible to deal with it. So you already answer it ;)

Comment: I cannot answer that. That is a question of computing power and storage capacity. Also of performance. To answer such questions you typically have to experiment.

Comment: Your approach isn't necessarily wrong, but I have a hunch that it is. How expensive are the calculations you are carrying out?  If you wanted to introduce another item or level 8 items, will it still make sense given that 72^6 is 139,314,069,504?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem seems appropriate.  I know how to generate those combinations, and how to insert them into a database.  But I can't imagine what end task this would make sense for.

Comment: Each combinaison will give an amount of token, the tool would be used to find the combinaison that give more token than a previous combinaison.

Answer (score 0):

All combinations can be mapped from the numbers from 0 to 1 934 917 631.  It just takes some DIVs and MODs to split an integer into 5 numbers, each between 0 and 71.  That might be a better starting point.

And if you want to store those 2 billion rows on disk, consider storing just 2 billion numbers, then pick them apart to find the 5 thingies.

In MySQL, a row with 5 `TINYINT UNSIGNED` columns is another approach.  It's not quite as compact as a single `INT UNSIGNED`, but it might (or might not) be easier to work with.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code to generate all the combinations:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int n = arr.length;
    int r = 3;
    int[] data = new int[r];
    combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n - 1, 0, r);
}

static void combinationUtil(int[] arr, int[] data, int start, int end, int index, int r) {
    if (index == r) {
        for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) {
            System.out.print(data[j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = start; i <= end && end - i + 1 >= r - index; i++) {
        data[index] = arr[i];
        combinationUtil(arr, data, i + 1, end, index + 1, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged with PHP and MySQL, I don’t think OP is looking for a solution in Java